# Find subset of vectors which form basis

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis, schauder-basis, dimension-theory-algebra

### Question

Let W be the subspace of $R^5$ spanned by
$ u_1
= (1, 2, –1, 3, 4)\\
u_2 = (2, 4, –2, 6, 8) \\
u_3 = (1, 3, 2, 2, 6)\\ u_4 = (1, 4, 5, 1, 8)\\u_5 = (2, 7, 3, 3, 9)$

Find a subset of the vectors which form
a basis of W.

### Doubt

Now. I understand that, I need to make a matrix and by doing row operations have to convert it to reduced echelon form, and the zero rows suggest the Linearly dependent(LD) vectors, but I don't think this is a correct method because, after few operations, when I see 2 rows of matrix which looks scalar multiple of each other, it's onto me that which row I want to make zero(true, isn't it ?),so it will change the answer

Comment: You have the right idea, put them in a matrix and do row reduction. The rows that don't become zero tell you which vectors span the space. The answer isn't unique so don't worry which row you pick to zero out, just keep track of which vector is in which row. If you swap them make sure you swap the original order that you put them into the matrix too.

Comment: Do your "W" and your "w" mean the same fhing?  Please use consistent notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, it doesn't matter which rows you choose to subtract and zero out, as long as you follow the operations of Gaussian elimination and arrive at the row-echelon form. Bases don't need to be unique. You're good as long as they span the same space.

Put all your vectors in a matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    {1} & 2 &  1  & 1 & 4\\
    {2} & 4  & 3  & 4 & 8 \\
    {-1} & -2  & 2  & 5 & 6 \\
    {3} & 6  & 2  & 1 & 8 \\
    {4} & 8  & 6  & 8 & 9\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
this should reduce to:

\begin{bmatrix}
    {1} & 2 &  0  & -1 & 0\\
    {0} & 0  & 1  & 2 & 0 \\
    {0} & 0  & 0  & 0 & 1 \\
    {0} & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
    {0} & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

Pick the vectors that correspond to the pivot columns to get the following basis: $B = \{ u_1, u_3, u_5\}$